# Decode a column in a dataframe and remove "b'\xc2\xa" n "\xc2\xa0"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two problems.

1. All my columns begin with the letter 'b'. I want to get rid of this character and convert all the values to float. (I've attached an image of the entire data frame).

[image]

2. For the Price column, there is this additional encoding "\xc2\xa". I want to remove that and keep the decimal value. (I've attached a picture of this column).

[image]

I was able to remove the 'b' character for this column by converting the column to string and then using this code:

```
price.replace('b','')
```

But when I tried this code with "\xc2\xa", it didn't work. I also think converting all the columns to string is a little inefficient so what's a better alternative?

This is my entire code if it helps:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Base_url = ("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/fxTracker/optChainDataByExpDates.jsp")

page = requests.get(Base_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table_it = soup.find_all(class_="opttbldata")

spot = soup.select_one("div:contains('REFERENCE RATE') > strong").text
ATM = (round(float(spot)*4))/4
OTMCE = ATM + 0.50
OTMPE = ATM - 0.50

table_cls_1 = soup.find_all(id = "octable")
col_list = []

for mytable in table_cls_1:
    table_head = mytable.find('thead')

    try:
        rows = table_head.find_all('tr')
        for tr in rows:
            cols = tr.find_all('th')
            for th in cols:
                er = th.text
                ee = er.encode('utf-8')
                col_list.append(ee)
    except:
        print('no thread')

col_list_fnl = [e for e in col_list if e not in ('CALLS', 'PUTS', 'Chart', '\xc2\xa0')]

table_cls_2 = soup.find(id = "octable")
all_trs = table_cls_2.find_all('tr')
req_row = table_cls_2.find_all('tr')

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(req_row)-3),columns = col_list_fnl)

row_marker = 0

for row_number, tr_nos in enumerate(req_row):
    if row_number <= 1 or row_number == len(req_row)-1:
        continue # To insure we only choose non empty rows

    td_columns = tr_nos.find_all('td')

    # Removing the graph column
    select_cols = td_columns[1:22]
    cols_horizontal = range(0,len(select_cols))

    for nu, column in enumerate(select_cols):

        utf_string = column.get_text()
        utf_string = utf_string.strip('\n\r\t": ')
        tr = utf_string.encode('utf-8')

        df.iloc[row_marker,[nu]] = tr

    row_marker += 1

print(df)
```

Comment: Replace `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')` with `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')`. If you don't want bytes, don't ask for it.

Comment: @cs95 I'm still getting the 'b' character before every value. I also want the values as decimals and not string. Sorry I'm new to web scraping/data cleansing!

Comment: It's probably because of this unnecessary line as well: `ee = er.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: And also `tr = utf_string.encode('utf-8')`. Why do you keep encoding things? That converts strings to bytes -- not what you want, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @cs95 If I remove the code: `tr = utf_string.encode('utf-8')`, I get this error: cannot copy sequence with size 53 to array axis with dimension 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code according to the comments from @cs95 and @eyllanesc. I can execute the code without errors and it yields a dataframe without byte encoding.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Base_url = ("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/fxTracker/optChainDataByExpDates.jsp")

page = requests.get(Base_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
table_it = soup.find_all(class_="opttbldata")

spot = soup.select_one("div:contains('REFERENCE RATE') > strong").text
ATM = (round(float(spot)*4))/4
OTMCE = ATM + 0.50
OTMPE = ATM - 0.50

table_cls_1 = soup.find_all(id = "octable")
col_list = []

for mytable in table_cls_1:
    table_head = mytable.find('thead')

    try:
        rows = table_head.find_all('tr')
        for tr in rows:
            cols = tr.find_all('th')
            for th in cols:
                er = th.text
                col_list.append(er)
    except:
        print('no thread')

col_list_fnl = [e for e in col_list if e not in ('CALLS', 'PUTS', 'Chart', '\xc2\xa0')]

table_cls_2 = soup.find(id = "octable")
all_trs = table_cls_2.find_all('tr')
req_row = table_cls_2.find_all('tr')

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(req_row)-3),columns = col_list_fnl)

row_marker = 0

for row_number, tr_nos in enumerate(req_row):
    if row_number <= 1 or row_number == len(req_row)-1:
        continue # To insure we only choose non empty rows

    td_columns = tr_nos.find_all('td')

    # Removing the graph column
    select_cols = td_columns[1:22]
    cols_horizontal = range(0,len(select_cols))

    for nu, column in enumerate(select_cols):

        utf_string = column.get_text()
        utf_string = utf_string.strip('\n\r\t": ')
        tr = utf_string

        df.iloc[row_marker,[nu]] = tr

    row_marker += 1

display(df)
```

This prints:

[image]

**Addition**

To properly convert columns to unique names and the values to float values do this:

```
cols = ['_first_col', 'Chart ', 'OI', 'Change in OI', 'Volume', 'IV', 'LTP', 'BidQty',
       'BidPrice', 'AskPrice_01', 'AskQty', 'Strike Price', 'BidQty', 'BidPrice',
       'AskPrice_02', 'AskQty', 'LTP', 'IV', 'Volume', 'Change in OI', 'OI',
       'Chart']
df.columns = cols

df.AskPrice_01 = df.AskPrice_01.apply(lambda x: float(x) if x != "-" else None)

df.AskPrice_02 = df.AskPrice_02.apply(lambda x: float(x) if x != "-" else None)
```

To filter a specific column you can use this:

```
df[df.AskPrice_01 > 65.25].AskPrice_01
```

I hope this helps. Good luck with your project!

Comment: is there a way I can check if the 'AskPrice' column starts with 65.25 and then show only that row? It seems like the values in that column are in this format: \xa065.2500\xa0\n1

Comment: To filter on a specific column you can use `df[df.AskPrice > 65.25]`. I see that you have two columns names `AskPrice`. You need to fix that to unique names.

Comment: I resolved that issue by using index numbers: `price = df.iloc[:,9:10]`. For e.g. I want to check if price `contains` the value 65.5. I tried `price.str.contains(65.5)` but I'm getting a 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str' error

Comment: See my addition to the answer. Your values still were strings or contain strings that you need to convert to float or int values.

Comment: OMG this works perfectly THANK YOU FOR EVERYTHING i wish i could upvote this 1000x